# What does query.executeUpdate() return in hibernate for create table query

Tags: hibernate

```
String sql="create table temptable (name varchar(2 Byte))";
    Transaction tx=session1.beginTransaction();
    Query query=session1.createSQLQuery(sql);
    int a=query.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println(a);tx.commit();
```

Why does it print 0 even after a successfull table creation and also with a drop table query .whereas it is stated that it returns the number of entities updated or deleted ,shouldnt it return 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table creation and dropping does not technically affect any database entities; hence why it returns 0.  Only during INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE will you see non-zero values.

Answer (score 7):

It return the number of rows affected. In your case no rows are updated/deleted, that's why it return 0.

`executeUpdate()` should be used for execution of update or delete statements over entities, not for DDL queries.